# preventing iPhone app users from logging in into multiple devices

Tags: ios, authentication, authorization

I'm creating a book library app, where people buy an account and become able to read all the books...

In the past, we were able to get the UDID of the iOS device and the login only works from this specific UDID.. now apple prevents this, another solutions were there like OPEN-UDID but now doesn't work...

Are there any other means to prevent the user from giving the credentials to another people??

The only solution on top of my head now is this :-

When a user login, a flag on the server becomes true, and when another account try to login using the same credentials, it will show an error message "you are already logged in on another device".. when the original user logs out, the flag becomes false.. this will prevent the account from being used on multiple devices at the same time.. but the drawback is, what if the user unInstalls the app without logging out?

Is there a research on this topic that covers all these scenarios?

Is there a way to use apple keychain or iCloud or any other solution ?

Comment: Why downvote guys please at least leave comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is on new login invalidate api request(and send them to login screen) of previous login you can use device token with each api to check if you want to send data to device or it's a old login token and needs redirect to login. you have to just store a device token for each account login if it matches then send data else redirect to login

**Edit 1:**

if you uninstall the app then you have to login again from other device to access the books(data) and in each login you'll replace the old token with new one. Now only device which has this new token can access books. All other device if there are any login left in any device then they will get message from API that token not matched and you have to redirect them to login page again

Comment: the device token is not persistent like before, if the app is uninstalled and installed again, the device token changes... I will upvote your answer because you are trying to help...

Comment: if you uninstall the app then you have to login again from other device to access the books(data) and in each login you'll replace the old token with new one. Now only device which has this new token can access books. All other device if there are any login left in any device then they will get message from API that token not matched and you have to redirect them to login page again

Comment: This is the correct way to solve this, only 1 token at a time ensure only one device can be logged in with it

Comment: good, so basically when I login, then I refresh the token on the database, and prevent old tokens from logging in, this will solve the problem! thanks

Comment: pleases add your comment to the answer so people can see it, your answer is accepted now because it solves the problem, many thanks.